# Battery shows charging then wall then charging then wall

Tags: 18.04, power-management

The best way I can explain this is when connected to AC, once the battery is charged and AC is left connected the battery icon will keep flipping back and forth as in shows battery then charging then battery then charging again. Sometimes is stays on AC for a while, but then will flip back and forth a bunch then hold. Its quite annoying seeing this up in the corner while working. Also worried it will ruin the internal battery.

Comment: Why? Lithium-ion batteries (the choice of nearly all manufacturers nowadays) have internal circuitry to avoid an overcharge, as overcharges can lead to heat and even fire. Therefore, when the battery reaches an specified voltage level, it stops charging. When the voltage drops due to self discharge or cooling, it starts charging again. This is normal.

Comment: So then my question is why when I use the previous kernel it does not happen, if it does its once and a while, unnoticeable, on the newest kernel i constantly see it happening. This is when I am doing something or nothing at all. Per your comment it would be happening while using power vs not using power, this is not the case.

Comment: Previous kernel may have let it discharge longer and waiter more until recharging.

Answer (score 0):

Cellphones exhibit this same behaviour. It lets the battery drain some then recharges. Phones have a built in "glitch" (not the best word but it gets the point across) that still shows 100% during the top 10% or so, the. It will reach 99% after that and then starts dropping and evens out along the way.

As to why it is not still, my guess would be that the previous kernel had a fix for this and the next one either removed it or (more likely) has an error/glitch with it. Have you tried updating to 19? I have not had this issue.